# Infopath 2010: date and time picker action if time is over 18:00 any date

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010

As the title says i have a infopath form where i want to run a extra action on submit if the time is greater than 18:00 but it can be any date.

I tried using 2 separate fields but that upset SharePoint (the data goes into a SharePoint calender hence not using 2 separate fields)

Thanks for your help

Lewis

Comment: If its after 18:00 it needs to be emailed to another person

Comment: And what does "emailed" mean here? InfoPath is just an external program that renders a list item using Javascript. Do you want to email the rendered screen (hard), the list item contents (easy but ugly) or a link to the list item (easiest)? Would sending an alert on creation after hours be enough?

Comment: The email part is not the problem i just need to know how to say if time > 18:00 using a rule